# Cast DateTime to DateTime with Commas C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert *DateTime* to a *DateTime* formatted with commas. This is required for the calendar appointment.Start (EWS Managed API):

```
appointment.Start = new DateTime(2014, 1, 2, 9, 0, 0);
```

but I want to do:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
appointment.Start = new DateTime(myDateTime);
```

This errors

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.DateTime(long)'
>   has some invalid arguments.

Obviously missing arguments, but I have no idea which ones!

Comment: Look at the following link for info on C# DateTime formatting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just do:

```
appointment.Start = DateTime.Now;
```

`DateTime` instance is `DateTime` instance, no matter which constructor overload you use, or which static property you choose to obtain specific instance.

And because `DateTime` is immutable, you don't care if someone else uses the same instance: he can't change it.

Comment: I can't believe I've been so dumb. Was following the MSDN example and assumed it had to be written like that. Will I ever get the hang of this c# stuff!

Answer (score 2):

If you really need it formatted like that - you'll need to break your DateTime into it's components

```
= new DateTime(myDateTime.Year, myDateTime.Month, myDateTime.Day, myDateTime.Hour, myDateTime.Minute,myDateTime.Second);
```

But I honestly and truly have no idea why you'd want something like that

Comment: That's not different from `= myDateTime` at all... Maybe just skips the milliseconds, but I don't think OP cares about that.

Comment: I know. I don't understand the purpose of the question either. I can only assume there's some custom-made DateTime for use with that library which only has the above constructor.

Comment: I was strictly following the example on MSDN and in my ignorance  I didn't realize the answer was in plain sight and simple.  Used appointment.Start = DateTime.Now;

Answer (score 1):

You are having a formatting issue? Then you have to tell us more about that 'appointment' of yours. Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It shows you how to format dates, but for formatting you need strings